# what is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit os in installing Java Application

Tags: java

what is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit os in installing Java Application,exclude JDK
and the expand of the pointer,is anything else?

Comment: have you consider [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=difference+between+32-bit+and+64-bit+os+in+installing+Java+Application) instead?

Answer (score 1):

The only differences between 32-bit and 64-bit builds of any program are the sizes of machine words, the amount of addressable memory, and the Operating System ABI in use.

With Java, the language specification means that the differences in machine word size and OS ABI should not matter at all unless you're using native code as well. (Native code must be built to be the same as the word-size of the JVM that will load it; you can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit builds in the same process without very exotic coding indeed, and you shouldn't be doing that with Java about.)

The 64 bit Java version also provided access to >4GB of heap size(if you rally need that)

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit OS allows you to run 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs, A 32-bit OS can only run 32-bit JVMs.

A 64-bit JVM can address more memory, use more, wider registers. Note: a 64-bit JVM can still use 32-bit references.